# Laravel 4 - Query Builder Left Join

Tags: join, laravel, left-join

I want to perform Laravel4 Query Builder Left Join. Here is my code:

```
$settings = DB::table('settings')
 ->leftJoin('users', 'settings.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')->get();
```

With this part of code I get all fields from both database table. I want to get all fields from **settings table** but just country and currency field from **users table**. Can someone help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `->get()` which is used to get all columns you need to use `->select()` to say which columns you want and then use `get()`

```
$settings = DB::table('settings')
->leftJoin('users', 'settings.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
->select('settings.*', 'users.country', 'users.currency')->get();
```

Comment: Do in need ->get() on end, I want to send result as JSON response ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `get()` after `select` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, pass fields to select in `get()` as array:

```
$settings = DB::table('settings')
              ->leftJoin('users', 'settings.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
              ->get(array('settings.*', 'users.country', 'users.currency'));
```

Using `->select('settings.*', 'users.country', 'users.currency')` you still need to call `get()` at the end, like this:

```
$settings = DB::table('settings')
              ->leftJoin('users', 'settings.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
              ->select('settings.*', 'users.country', 'users.currency')->get();
```